# numerate new versions of a file copied into a folder

Tags: powershell, copy, rename

I have a file that is generated daily. It is generated with the filename `dailyfile.dat`.

The file needs to be copied into a destination folder and numerated with a single digit that is one higher than the file already in the destination folder so that all files coexist and have no gap in numeration.

In other words, I need each day's copy to add +1 to whatever is already in the destination folder. If 0,1 & 2 exist in the destination folder, then the new copy placed in the destination should be named 3 and so on. If no files exist, it gets named 0.

i.e.

- Exists

  ```
  c:\source\dailyfile.dat
  c:\destination\dailyfile0.dat
  ```
- process

  ```
  copy c:\source\dailyfile.dat -> c:\destination\dailyfile1.dat
  ```
- results

  ```
  c:\destination\dailyfile0.dat
  c:\destination\dailyfile1.dat
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```psh
$src       = 'c:\source\dailyfile.dat'
$dstFolder = 'c:\destination'

$f = Get-Item $src

$n = 0
do {
  $dst = Join-Path $dstFolder ($f.BaseName + $n + $f.Extension)
  $n++
} while (Test-Path -LiteralPath $dst)

Copy-Item $src $dst
```

Comment: Thanks Ansgar

This is doing what I need when there is no file in the destination folder but the 'do statement' is hanging when a file already exists in the destination. folder.

Comment: @Mike My mistake. I forgot the step where `$n` is incremented. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could parse the name of the file, get the number off the end, select the highest number, and add one to create the new path. This has the advantage of being able to "pick up where you left off" if you ever archive some of your daily files.

```psh
$src       = 'c:\source\dailyfile.dat'
$dstFolder = 'c:\destination'
[int32]$LastFile = Get-ChildItem $dstFolder |
                   Where {$_.BaseName -match "^dailyfile(\d+)"} |
                   ForEach {$Matches[1]} |
                   Sort -Descending |
                   Select -First 1
If ($LastFile) {$LastFile++} else {$LastFile = 0}
$Dest = "C:\Destination\DailyFile$LastFile.dat"
Copy-Item $src -Dest $Dest
```

This way if you archive them annually or something in a couple years you would end up with (assuming you always leave at least 1 file in the folder):

```
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----         5/21/2015   7:47 PM            2015
d----         5/21/2016   7:47 PM            2016
-a---         5/21/2017   2:00 PM     580984 DailyFile730.dat
-a---         5/22/2017   2:00 PM     392610 DailyFile731.dat
```

Comment: I would make the pattern more specific (`^dailyfile(\d+)$`), otherwise it might match things that shouldn't be matched.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I agree, and have updated my answer to reflect that. Thank you, your input is awesome as always!

Comment: Flattery will get you nowhere. :þ

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Ansgar's post, if you can include a separator character like _ then you could use:

```
    $src       = 'c:\source\dailyfile.dat'
    $dstFolder = 'c:\destination'

    #Get the number from the last file in the destination directory
    [int]$NextNum = [int](gci $dstFolder | Sort-Object -Property Basename | Select -Last 1).basename.split("_")[1] + 1

    #Get source file
    $f = Get-Item $src
    # Add more zeros in the ToString for more padding
    $dst = Join-Path $dstFolder ($f.BaseName + "_" + $NextNum.ToString("000") + $f.Extension)
    Copy-Item $src $dst
```